# Регулярное выражение для пароля от 4 до 12 символов с использованием любых символов, кроме специальных

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Никак не могу составить регулярное выражение для пароля. Пароль должен содержать от 4 до 12 символов с использованием любых символов, кроме специальных.

```
/^(.{4,12})([^!@#$%^&*]{1,})$//
```

Вот что получилось у меня, но он не совсем соответсвует условиям. После 12 символов почему-то пароль валидный. И спецсимволы делают пароль невалидным только в конце введеных символов. Как бы это можно было поправить?

Comment: `[^!@#$%^&*]{4,12}`

Comment: Ваше выражение ищет: ``(.{4,12})`` от 4 до 12 ЛЮБЫХ символов (кроме конца строки), после которых идет более одного символа, за исключением указанных ``!@#$%^&*``. Т.е. есть общие слова с требованиями к паролю, но в целом совсем не то.

Comment: В зависимости от метода ЯП использующего регулярное выражение в некоторых случаях нужно ограничить строку символами начала и конца строки `^[^!@#$%^&*]{4,12}$` а для их работы часто нужно указывать параметр регулярного выражения `m` - multiline.

Comment: А что значит "любых символов, кроме специальных"? Например, что делать с \t, \n и далее куча всякого. Может быть стоит решать задачу от обратного? Указать множество символов, допустимых для пароля и сравнить, ввод с шаблоном на 1) попадает в шаблон, 2( тождественно равен найденному регулярным выражением блоку. Скорее всего под условие "кроме спец символов" попадает регулярное выражение ^[-\w]{4,12}$ - от 4 до 12 символов начала до конца строки от 4 до 12 символов, содержащих "-", любые цифры, буквы или знак подчеркивания